# Find first value in table then output a specific column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I currently have a formula setup:

INDEX(table1,(SUMPRODUCT((A1=table1)*ROW(table1))-ROW(table1)),20)

If it finds the value of A1 anywhere in table1, find its row then return the 20th column in table1.

I noticed the limitation of this due to fact that the table will have repeat values...is there other methods to achieve this, perhaps by finding only the first value?

Comment: INDEX and MATCH?

Comment: Thanks SJR, would that work with repeat values in the table?

Comment: Sorry I thought you wanted only the first value. Do you want repeated values separately identified? If so, you'll need an array formula probably.

Comment: No, sorry I misworded. SUMPRODUCT actually gives me error and weird results when there are repeats in the table. The first value is what I want, I will test it now...thank you.

Comment: @Dergyll your question says “find first value...” index and match will do that, if you need to deal with duplicates then there are questions on here that cover dealing with duplicates - you just need to search.

Comment: @SJR the OP wants the first row and column reference of the same value.  If the values can duplicated sometimes the column reference will reference one of the dups and the row reference will reference another.  The OP wants to ensure that they reference the same.  The real question is the definition of `First`.  Does that mean the first going left to right or top to bottom?

Comment: @Scott Craner - ok, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @ScottCraner Top Down meaning A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3,C1,C2,C3... Left Right meaning A1,B1,C1,A2,B2,C2,A3,B3,C3? If that's the case, then actually either would work, if I had to pick then Left-Right.